# SBCL warning that a variable is defined but never used

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I'm getting a warning from the sbcl compiler, that a variable has been defined but is not used. And the compiler is right. I want to get rid of the warning, but don't know how to do it. Here is an example:

```
(defun worker-1 (context p)
  ;; check context (make use of context argument)
  (if context
      (print p)))

 (defun worker-2 (context p)
   ;; don't care about context
   ;; will throw a warning about unused argument
   (print p))

 ;;
 ;; calls a given worker with context and p
 ;; doesn't know which arguments will be used by the
 ;; implementation of the called worker
 (defun do-cmd (workerFn context p)
   (funcall workerFn context p))

 (defun main ()
    (let ((context ()))
     (do-cmd #'worker-1 context "A")
     (do-cmd #'worker-2 context "A")))
```

The do-cmd-function expects worker-functions that implement a specific interface f(context p).

The sbcl compiler throws the following warning:

```
in: DEFUN WORKER-2
;     (DEFUN WORKER-2 (CONTEXT P) (PRINT P))
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
 ;   The variable CONTEXT is defined but never used.
;
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to declare that the parameter is intentionally [ignored](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/d_ignore.htm).

```
(defun worker-2 (context p)
  (declare (ignore context))
  (print p))
```

`ignore` will also signal a warning if you *do* use the variable. To suppress warnings in both cases, you can use the declaration `ignorable`, but this should only be used in macros and other such cases where it's not *possible* to determine whether the variable will be used at the point of its declaration.

In case you are not yet familiar with `declare`, note that it is not an operator, and instead can only appear in [certain locations](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_declar.htm); in particular, it must be located before all forms in the `defun` body, though it can be either above or below a documentation string.